# How to move a file 'to a directory that's on your PATH'?

Tags: path, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Im trying to install a JSON formatter for Cucumber but am having trouble configuring it. The steps (listed [here](https://github.com/cucumber/json-formatter)) go like this:

```
 1. Download cucumber-json-formatter-darwin-amd64 and rename it to cucumber-json-formatter
 2. Move it to a directory that's on your PATH
 3. Make it executable with chmod +x cucumber-json-formatter
 4. Verify that you can run it: cucumber-json-formatter --help
```

I have the file downloaded and renamed correctly. However, I am stuck on the second step of moving it to a directory thats on my `PATH`.

Doing some research, I know what the folder structure looks like but I'm not sure exactly what the step is instructing. How would I achieve this step? Can it be in ANY directory on my `PATH`? I am currently using a Mac if that makes any difference for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

> 2. Move it to a directory that's on your PATH

PATH refers to the machine's environment variable named `PATH`. Any time the OS is asked to execute something `PATH` is searched.

On Windows open System Properties dialog, click Environment Variables button and Path is listed there. You can add a new entry for the location of `cucumber-json-formatter` or you can move it to an existing Path entry.

Answer (score 0):

To set up the PATH for the Cucumber JSON formatter on a Mac, you can follow these steps:

1. Identify the directory where the Cucumber JSON formatter executable is located. Let's assume it's in `/path/to/cucumber-json-formatter`.
2. Open Terminal on your Mac. You can find it in the "Utilities" folder within the "Applications" folder, or you can use Spotlight Search (Cmd + Space) and type "Terminal" to launch it.
3. Once the Terminal is open, you need to edit the `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` file in your home directory. To do this, run the following command to open the file in a text editor:

   ```bash
   open ~/.bash_profile
   ```

   or

   ```bash
   open ~/.zshrc
   ```

   If either of these files doesn't exist, the command will create a new one.
4. Add the following line to the file, replacing `/path/to/cucumber-json-formatter` with the actual path to the Cucumber JSON formatter directory:

   ```bash
   export PATH="/path/to/cucumber-json-formatter:$PATH"
   ```
5. Save the file and exit the text editor.
6. Close and reopen Terminal to apply the changes to the PATH.
7. Verify that the PATH is set up correctly by running the following command in Terminal:

   ```bash
   which cucumber-json-formatter
   ```

   If the setup was successful, it should display the path to the cucumber-json-formatter executable.

Now you should be able to use the Cucumber JSON formatter from any directory by simply typing its name in the Terminal.